# How do we construct a parametrization of a very specific ellipse on the plane that's bounded?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, parametric, parametrization

I'm trying to construct a parametrization of the biggest ellipse whose y's $\in$ $(0,1]$ and whose x's $\in$ $[-1,1]$. I know that the equation of an ellipse of $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2$=1. I've played around with the equation and haven't been able to make the biggest ellipse whose minimum x = -1, whose maximum x=1, i,e. domain $\in$ [-1,1] and whose codomain or y-values range from $\in$ (0,1] even in standard form so I don't know how I'll make the equation into parametric form.

Edit:

I'm actually not trying to find the biggest ellipse. I'm just trying to find some ellipse that must go through (-1,1) to (1,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2+\frac{(y-1)^2}{0.9^2} =1$$
has parametrization
$$(x,y)=(\cos t, 1+0.9\sin t),$$
where $\pi\leq t\leq 2\pi$.

Comment: I'm looking for a boundary which is a simple closed oriented curve called C where 0<y<=1 for all points (x,y) on the curve C that goes from (-1,1) to (1,1). I guess I'm not looking for a curve with the point (0,0). I suppose an ellipse could be such a curve C.

Comment: You mean with $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$ lying on $C$? And $C$ is an ellipse? And $y\in(0,1]$?

Comment: This isn't possible unless you get rid of the condition $y\in(0,1]$.

Comment: The simple oriented curve is from (-1,1) to (1,1) So I suppose I'm not looking for an ellipse. I'm looking for a semicircle that's bounded by being closed up at y=1 and centered somewhere convenient so that it's top boundary is y=1 and bounded below so that y is never 0 and the semicircle has a minimum x=-1 and maximum x=1.

Comment: So something like $x^2+\frac{(y-1)^2}{0.9^2} =1$?

Comment: Right, I'm just not sure how to after parametrizing that circle only get the bottom half of the circle by bounding t, the parametrization parameter.

Comment: It's an ellipse. The parameterisation is $(x,y)=(\cos t, (1+0.9\sin t))$, where $\pi\leq t\leq 2\pi$